# Setting html checkbox checked value based on mvc model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an Edit view where I have some checkboxes that I need populated based on values from the model. I would like to avoid using different CheckBoxListFor extensions, as I believe there is a simpler way to do it.

I tried to set the value with javascript, but I end up with all checkboxes checked, which is not ok.
This is what I tried:

```
function SetAdminCheckBox() {
    var contains = @Model.RoleNames.Contains("Admin");
    var True = true;
    var result;

    result = contains ? 'checked' : '';

    return result;
}

<input type="checkbox" name="roleNames" value="Admin" checked="SetAdminCheckBox()"/>
```

Comment: Does RoleNames only have that specific users role or all 'roles' because that could be why?

Comment: Attribute checked has only one possible value : "checked", "SetAdminCheckBox()" is not a valid string value. You need to read the HTML language documentation.

Comment: @Virus721, I know this, but I'm trying to pass an empty string if the role is not in the RoleNames list. Which is what I can't seem to be able to.

Comment: Only event attributes may contain javascript code, SetAdminCheckBox() is not executed.

Comment: @CodeBlend, RoleNames contains all the roles the current object (a notification) applies to. In my test case, it only contains one role name, but using functions like the one I described to set the other checkboxes, they also get set.

Comment: @Virus721, I see what you meen; still, is there a way you would recommend setting the checked attribute ?

Comment: I don't know how to use ASP, but in PHP i would do : `'<input type="checkbox" name="roleNames" value="Admin"'.($contains ?  'checked="checked"' : '').' />'`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, using some razor syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roleNames" value="Admin" @if (Model.RoleNames.Contains("Admin")) {<text>checked="checked"</text>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use "checked" attribute like that, checked has no value it is either present or not if it is present than checkbox is checked otherwise not

use an if to write two version one which will output checked attribute and other which will not.